# doing a trial run to calculate gas before submitting a transaction

Tags: gas, gas-estimate

I'm wondering if there is a possibility of doing a trial run of a transaction so that the gas can be worked out before submitting to the network?

I know that there are estimates but in certain cases like a for or a while loop, it would be nice to figure out a pretty exact number for the gas limit before submission.

Am I missing something or is it just really difficult to determine gas fees before hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in most cases, it's impossible to get an exact estimate since previous transactions included in the same block can modify the contracts state and change your call's gas consumption. Now the `eth_estimategas` RPC method will run your transaction off chain and try to provide the best estimate it can, but you shouldnt expect it to be *exactly* the right value. For example, when estimating gas consumption, metamask runs eth_estimategas and multiplies it with 1.5 for safety.

Comment: thanks for that. how does `eth_estimategas` do that? does it have it's own evm implementation?

Comment: It runs the transaction off chain (using the latest data it has) following the EVM rules for calculating gas usag, and returns the gas used,

Comment: makes a lot of sense. thanks for that.